# Formula based on a chart

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a chart that needs to be turned into a formula.  Essentially you would cross reference by **brand** and **number of rooms** to return the **number referenced**. *EX. Hotel A with 300 rooms return "1608".*

I would also like to keep a VLOOKUP formula to populate the brand and room count in separate columns that are the reference points for the chart formula.  Is that possible?  My nested formula is a hot mess (62 lines) and not worth pasting here.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Chart example]

[Spreadsheet snag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9TAL.png)

[VLOOKUP issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWegh.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please clarify what "I have a chart that needs to be turned into a formula" means, that statement makes no sense (to me, at least)

Comment: Need to turn the picture into a workable chart.  If I choose brand A in column B and 180 Rooms in column C, it should return 684.  Have to have a formula that deals with all variations.  Currently have a 62 line nested formula because I have 7 brands and 11 sets of room counts.  The issue is most likely the VLOOKUP formula that pulls the Brand and Room count from another tab, so the if formula doesn't work.

Comment: why is the result you've described as a 'snag' a snag? The output is correct. (Brand A  - 180 falls within the room number range that corresponds to 684). Look up the INDEX function, you may have more success using that instead of the VLookup (and I hope you have some kind of value  in the empty cells, e.g. 0 or N/A)

Comment: Please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54718023/edit). Please don't add information in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do two things in order that should get down what you ask.

First, you want to transform your Rooms column with the LEFT/FIND functions:

```
     =LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)*1
```

This will return the lowest number of rooms from which on you reach a next bracket and turn it into a number that you can use for your lookup.

Then, assuming you have your original Room column in `A`, your transformed room column in `B`, and your BrandA - BrandC columns in `C:E`, use an [INDEX MATCH](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/index-match-formula-excel/) formula will do the sorting for you and return the correct value:

```
    =INDEX(C:E,MATCH(G3,B:B,1)+0,IF(H3="A",1,IF(H3="B",2,3)))
```

For it to work, you need to specify how many rooms you want in cell `G3` (or whatever reference you need for your purposes) and the letter of the brand (A, B or C) in cell `H3`. The formula will then look through the three result columns, select the one with the right room number and the right Brand and return the value.

Comment: Hi Rachel.  Thank you so much for your insight.  My apologies for forum etiquette, it's my first time posing a question.  Your explanation makes perfect sense, but the calculation seems one cell off.  If I put Brand B with 75 rooms, it populates as 276 versus the 180 it should be. Can't find my way around this error. Maybe I missed something?  Thanks again.

Comment: If you found the code helpful, please up-vote the solution.

Comment: The formula as you laid out works great.  The only problem is that I am using a VLOOKUP formula in columns B and D from another sheet in the workbook.  So Column C does not pull over anything but Brand A unless manually changed.  Here's the formula in that cell: =IF($B2="CW","C",IF($B2="SB","B","A"))  Any suggestions for me to work around the VLOOKUP issue? (labeled VLOOKUP issue in original post)

Comment: This seems to be a different issue. If you would like for the community to take a look at this, please write a new question for it, so this posting content stays unamibiguously tied to the original question.

Comment: Sounds great!  Will do.